# Boxplot factor across many samples with R

Tags: r

Given the data

```
  Step     A     B     C     D     E     F     G     I     J
1    1 0.158 0.011 0.099 6.504 5.914 0.000 0.100 0.330 0.000
2    2 0.345 0.016 0.102 6.050 5.285 0.000 0.102 0.316 0.001
3    1 0.324 0.015 0.100 7.146 6.426 0.000 0.101 0.293 0.000
4    2 0.264 0.015 0.099 5.864 5.202 0.000 0.101 0.296 0.000
5    1 0.346 0.022 0.101 5.889 5.027 0.000 0.101 0.411 0.000
6    2 0.397 0.022 0.130 6.061 5.311 0.000 0.131 0.220 0.000
7    1 0.337 0.015 0.048 7.417 6.839 0.000 0.110 0.129 0.000
8    2 0.362 0.016 0.143 5.726 4.951 0.001 0.144 0.268 0.000
9    1 0.178 0.011 0.099 5.831 5.290 0.000 0.100 0.261 0.000
```

`d < - read.table('sample.txt', header=T)` gives me a data frame, and `boxplot(d$A ~ d$Step)` yields a reasonable graph, but I cannot seem to get all plots on the same graph. Something like `boxplot(d ~ d$Step)` is what I expected to work, but I get the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = d ~ d$Step) : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'd'
```

I've tried making Step a factor `d$Step <- as.factor(d$Step)` but that seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative is to plot these in base R each on their own scale, like this

```
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
for(i in 2:10) {
    boxplot(d[,i] ~ d$Step, main=names(d)[i]) }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(d, Var, Val, -Step) %>% 
       mutate(Step=factor(Step)) %>%
       ggplot(., aes(x=Var, y = Val, fill=Step)) +
          geom_boxplot() + 
          scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue"))
```

[image]

Comment: Can it not be done with the base R graphics? I'll look into `tidyverse`

Comment: @RobPaisley  It is easier with ggplot